# How to use scopes to filter data by partial variable

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I have some working script filtering my results with Active Record Scoping. Everything works fine when i want to filter by comparing params with data from database.

But i have some function counting car price inside _car.html.erb partial, the result of this function depends on params result.

How can i scope search results by result of this function and show only cars which are under some price (defined in params).

**Some code to make it more clear:**

car.rb (model file)

```
  scope :price_leasing, -> (price_leasing) { where('price_leasing <= ?', price_leasing) }
  # for now price_leasing is getting price from database
  scope :brand, -> (brand) { where brand: brand }
  scope :car_model, -> (car_model) { where car_model: car_model }
  scope :category, -> (category) { where category: category }
```

cars_controller.rb (controller file)

```
def index
  @cars = Car.where(nil)
  @cars = @cars.price_leasing(params[:price_leasing]) if params[:price_leasing].present?
  @cars = @cars.brand(params[:brand]) if params[:brand].present?
  @cars = @cars.car_model(params[:car_model]) if params[:car_model].present?
  @cars = @cars.category(params[:category]) if params[:category].present?

  @brands = Brand.all # importing all car brands into filters
end
```

in index.html.erb i have "render @cars" code

```
<%= 
  if @cars.size > 0
    render @cars.where(:offer_status => 1)
  else
    render html: '<p>Nie znaleziono  pasujących wyników.</p>'.html_safe
  end
 %>
```

inside _car.html.erb file i have function from helper

```
<h3 class="car-cell__price"><%= calculate_car_price(car.price, car.id) %> <span class="car-cell__light-text">zł/mc</span></h3>
```

my calculate_car_price() function inside helper

```
def calculate_car_price(car_price, car_id)
  car = Car.find(car_id)
  fullprice = car_price

  if params[:price_leasing].present?
    owncontribution = params[:price_leasing].to_i
  else
    owncontribution = car.owncontribution
  end 
  pv = fullprice - owncontribution + (0.02 * fullprice)

  if params[:period].present?
    carperiod = params[:period].to_i
    carprice = (Exonio.pmt(0.0522/60, carperiod, pv)) * -1
  else
    carprice = (Exonio.pmt(0.0522/60, 60, pv)) * -1
  end
  p number_with_precision(carprice, precision: 0)
end
```

i would love to scope by the result of this function. Is it possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question, but this is what I get from your question. You provide the `"price_leasing"` query parameter, but the `calculate_car_price` is still displaying prices above the provided `"price_leasing"` query parameter. Am I correct implying this from your question? If so could you add the logic of `calculate_car_price` to the question, since the same logic has to be applied to the query/scope to get matching results.

Comment: @3limin4t0r i've just added that method inside the main post, but you understand me wrong. I have "price_leasing" field in my database and for now i'm comparing params[:price_leasing] from my search engine with database "price_leasing" field. What i want to achieve is comparing "price_leasing" param from my search engine to the "calculate_car_price" method result. Is it clear? Sorry, if not

Answer (score 0):

The thing about scopes are that they are implemented at the database level. You want to select records that have a value

To do what you want at the DB level, you would need to a virtual column in the database, the implementation will change based on which database product you're using (I would not expect a virtual column definition in postgreSQL to be the same as a virtual column definition in mySQL)

So I'm not sure there's an optimal way to do this.

I would suggest you build your own class method and instance method in your model `Car`. It would be less performant but easier to understand and implement.

```
def self.car_price_under(target_price, params)
  select { |v| v.car_price_under?(target_price, params) }
end


def car_price_under?(target_price, params)
  full_price = price
  if params[:price_leasing].present?
     my_own_contribution = params[:price_leasing].to_i
   else
    my_own_contribution = owncontribution
  end 
  pv = full_price - my_own_contribution + (0.02 * full_price)
  if params[:period].present?
    car_period = params[:period].to_i
    new_car_price = (Exonio.pmt(0.0522/60, car_period, pv)) * -1
  else
    new_car_price = (Exonio.pmt(0.0522/60, 60, pv)) * -1
  end
  new_car_price <= target_price
end
```

This would let you do...

```
 @cars = Car.where(nil)
 @cars = @cars.brand(params[:brand]) if params[:brand].present?
 @cars = @cars.car_model(params[:car_model]) if params[:car_model].present?
 @cars = @cars.category(params[:category]) if params[:category].present?
 @cars = @cars.car_price_under(target_price, params) if target_price.present?
```

Note that this is happening in rails, NOT in the database, so the `car_price_under` method should be called after all other scopes to minimise the number of records that need to be examined.  You cannot chain additional scopes as `@cars` would be an array... if you want to be able to chain additional scopes (or you want an active record relation, not an array) you could do something like `@cars = Car.where(id: @cars.pluck(:id))`

Comment: Hello Steve, thank you for your answer, it's very complex and showed me some direction :) I have some syntax problem tho (linking to the select line):
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/git/alertbudget/app/models/car.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting '=' ...ce_under?{target_price, params} } ... ^ /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/git/alertbudget/app/models/car.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected end, expecting '}'

Comment: Hi, sorry, the line 3 should have been `select { |v| v.car_price_under?(target_price, params) }` I used brackets instead of parentheses.  The line 14 error I'm not sure about... can you post in your question the lines 1 through 14 of your car.rb?